# GWT CellTable Sort arow Icon on all sortable columns

Tags: java, gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

I'm having a `CellTable` with sortable Columns and it works like in the showcase ([GWT CellTable showcase](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable)). But I think this is not very user friendly. Because the sort arrow icon is only on 1 column and I think it should be an all (set to be) sortable columns. How can I have a arrow icon, with the same behavior, over all sortable columns. thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrow shows which column is currently sorted. If you put arrows on all columns, how will a user tell which column is currently used for sorting? I think it defeats the purpose of the arrow.

Comment: hm ok seems accurate too. but how can the user tell which column he is able to sort. whats the approach for that ?

Comment: @vicR Usually, that's indicated by the cursor. `cursor: pointer` (the small hand) is used if the header is sortable, `cursor: default` otherwise.

Comment: ah ok yeah thats true, ok this should be user friendly enough ^^ thanks for your input :)

Comment: Anderi,i read your answer ,but here i have one question how to perform  sorting on multiple column meaning i want to show icon on two column fields then how its possible ?Is this not a defects see the example smargwt link http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_sorting